# Meaning of "beating dad's record"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "beating dad's record"?

your mom is already beating dad's record. Only a matter of time before it ends. right?

Source of info: https://youtu.be/holzBghWTlY?t=290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include the quote before this, you get a full picture of what's going on:

> Girl 1: Just... we never really stay in the same place for longer than six months, so...
>
> Girl 2: Well, your mom's already beating my dad's record...

As you can see, the "record" to which the second girl is referring is the amount of time that her family stays in a particular location before moving. The second girl is being sarcastic, calling this a "record" out of annoyance.

Comment: can you explain the second sentence "only a matter of time before it ends"?

Comment: @Pankaj It's hard to know for sure, but "only a matter of time before it ends" potentially means "only a matter of time before **your stay with our family** ends". I haven't seen the show though, so I don't know definitively.

Comment: can you please rephrase this sentence in simple speech? **I had like to use this tutorial as a feedback session, where you reflect on the experience of doing the project.**

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the show, Girl 1 is declaring that her mother and herself will not be living with the driver of the car, Girl 2, for much longer. She's suggesting this would be consistent with her and her mother's flighty living pattern. Girl 2 then suggests that Girl 1's mom has outlasted her father's typical relationship duration, to which she is referring when she state's 'my dad's record.' Another reference of English vernacular is to say that the two single parents are 'shacking up.'

Comment: can you explain the second sentence "only a matter of time before it ends"?

Comment: Their respective parents' living arrangements, of living together as a family, are based on the parents' noted relationship (romance.) So Girl 2 is suggesting that her father and Girl 1's mother are bound to break up from, or end, that romantic relationship, after both girls have concluded in tone/mood, that they have not expected the romance to persist to the current time. The tone is then thus that: neither knows what it means, or how to be, with the event of a romance longer than 6 months. The specific endpoint of reference is of their parents' romance and their living in quarters together.

Comment: You mentioned "bound to break up from, or end, that romantic relationship, ", can you tell me the meaning of bound? I tried to look into dictionary but of no use to understand it in this context.

Comment: Sure, bound in that sense refers somewhat fatalistically/routinely (like saying 'destined' or 'fated' but more pragmatic, so moreso like 'presumptively' or 'expected') to actions. In the dictionary, bound may readily reference physical attachment etc, so in this sense it is a similar vibe to the physical, but bound to the pattern of their evidenced romantic relationships. We hear "chains of love" as a commonly manifest binding reference, and therein its reference would moreso be chains of breakups.

Comment: can you please rephrase this sentence in simple speech? **I had like to use this tutorial as a feedback session, where you reflect on the experience of doing the project.**